# Bizarre Xcode/iTunes Provisioning crash

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've been building and deploying apps for several months now and am aware that provisioning can get a bit sticky at times. But my current situation is particularly unusual.

I can attach my development device and build and run the app on it through Xcode. If I archive it for Ad-Hoc Distribution as an ipa file, I can also successfully load it onto a distribution device via iTunes. However, running it on the device causes an immediate crash: it opens then promptly closes.

There are no permissions errors during the iTunes load, and this issue presents so far on 3 distribution devices, including the same device that it successfully runs when sent via Xcode.

For the life of me I cannot figure out what is going on; in the past, if there was a misplaced profile or a device not added to the profile, you'd get a simple permissions error during the iTunes sync. I've never seen it successfully transfer to a device with no errors, but then crash. I'd love some suggestions as I've been working with this for 2 hours trying to track it all down.

All devices are in the provisioning profile and I reloaded the profiles in XCode to make sure they were current. I also reloaded the ad-hoc profile in iTunes to make it was current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar experience with expired provisioning profiles: dev build of an app opens then immediately closes when run on a device. Double check that all profiles installed on the devices are current.